# Eloquent error with count, group by and having

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I haves this working mysql query

```
select niv.*, count(en.estudiante) as inscritos
from niveles as  niv
inner join estudiante_nivel as en on en.nivel = niv.nivel_id
GROUP by niv.nivel_id
having (niv.estudiantes - inscritos) > 0
```

also in Laravel eloquent

```
$niveles = $colegio->_niveles()
                ->select('niveles.*', DB::raw("COUNT(en.estudiante) AS total"))
                ->join('estudiante_nivel as en', 'en.nivel', '=', 'niveles.nivel_id')
                ->groupBy('niveles.nivel_id')
                ->havingRaw("(niveles.estudiantes - total) > 0")
                ->orderBy('nombre')
                ->get();
```

But i get this error

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'kidsbook2.niveles.nombre' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `niveles`.*, COUNT(en.estudiante) AS total from `niveles` inner join `estudiante_nivel` as `en` on `en`.`nivel` = `niveles`.`nivel_id` where `niveles`.`colegio` = 4 and `niveles`.`colegio` is not null group by `niveles`.`nivel_id` having (niveles.estudiantes - total) > 0 order by `nombre` asc)
```

I've been reading that i have to put the total field within the group by but i still get an error.

What's the problem ? Anyone can help me out ?

Tables definition

```
CREATE TABLE `niveles` (
    `nivel_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `seccion` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `estudiantes` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `maestros` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `colegio` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`nivel_id`),
    INDEX `nivel_colegio_idx` (`colegio`),
    CONSTRAINT `nivel_colegio` FOREIGN KEY (`colegio`) REFERENCES `colegios` (`colegio_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)


CREATE TABLE `estudiante_nivel` (
    `en_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `estudiante` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `nivel` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`en_id`),
    INDEX `en_estudiante_idx` (`estudiante`),
    INDEX `en_nivel_idx` (`nivel`),
    CONSTRAINT `en_estudiante` FOREIGN KEY (`estudiante`) REFERENCES `estudiantes` (`estudiante_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `en_nivel` FOREIGN KEY (`nivel`) REFERENCES `niveles` (`nivel_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: You should provide a table structure and some sample data. This will help with getting a better idea with what's going wrong.

Comment: I think the error is on 'nombre' field, it seems there is additional order by clause on this field. (order by `nombre`) ?

Comment: Nothing, still getting the same error